# Loading bitmap images in Picasso Image loader slows down scrolling in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-imageview, picasso

I'm trying to generate a Thumbnail of a all videos which is found on sdcard folder and populate all the generated bitmaps in a listview using Picasso Image loader. Everything works fine but its very very slow, I cant able to scroll through the listveiew its lagging very much and slow . I have somewhere around 150 views in that listview. Any Help ?? .Thank is advance.

```
public class VideoFilesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private List<String> mpath;
    private Context mContext;
    public static ArrayList<String> mSelectedPaths = null;

    public VideoFilesAdapter(Context context, List<String> path) {
        super(context, R.layout.fileadapter_list, path);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mpath = path;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fileadapter_list, null);
        }
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        File file = new File(mpath.get(position));

        if (file.exists()) {

            txtTitle.setText(file.getName());

            Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                    file.getAbsolutePath(),
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

            Picasso.with(mContext).load(getImageUri(mContext, bitmap))
                    .centerInside().resize(100, 100)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.holder).error(R.drawable.error)
                    .into(imageView);

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, bytes);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),
                inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem of your code is that your Inflating TextView and ImageView every time a  cell-view is recycled, basically it will slowdown your scrolling experience.

Comment: So what is the solution for this ?? @Dragon

Comment: Im coding it now, I might send you by tomorrow :) and I will explain every part as I can.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
It doesn't look like you are storing/caching those bitmaps in any way, so it is doing it over and over again. Try the solution found here: [Video thumbnail arrayadopter is slow on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005248/video-thumbnail-arrayadopter-is-slow-on-scroll)

---

I don't think that Picasso is slowing down the scrolling of your `ListView`. How complex are your list items? If they nest many views, that could be it, I have had over 700 items in a `ListView` with no performance issues.

Comment: I know the slow down is because of `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail` function which generates Thumbnail of all the video files in the folders. is there any solution to fix it .

Answer (score 0):

As I review the code I've seen both `TextView` and `ImageView` is being inflated everytime `getView` is called. Inflation is a very expensive task so we would like to avoid using it as much as we can.

Before Anything else make sure you will declare it in your Gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

Add this helper class in your `VideoFilesAdapter.java`

```
 class Helper {
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView image;
  }
```

Then we will use LRUcache in storing images so that we can use this image over and over without doing to much task.

Add `MyLRU.java` in your project

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;

public class MyLRU {

    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = null;
    private static MyLRU myLru = null;

    private MyLRU() {
        int availableMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(availableMemory / 8) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
                // this is the only way to get the Bitmap size below API 12
                return (value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight()) / 1024;
            }
        };
    }

    public static MyLRU getInstance() {
        if (myLru == null) {
            myLru = new MyLRU();
        }
        return myLru;
    }

    public void addImage(String key, Bitmap image) {
        myLru.addImage(key, image);
    }

    public Bitmap getImage(String key) {
        return myLru.getImage(key);
    }

}
```

Add a utility method in your `VideoFilesAdapter.java`

```
public static Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
        int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

        // Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
        // To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger
        // of these two.
        float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
        float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
        float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

        // Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
        float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
        float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

        // Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
        // should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
        float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
        float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

        // The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
        // be
        RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);

        // Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
        // scaled bitmap onto it.
        Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
        canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

        return dest;
    }
```

Here is the Full modification of your `VideoFilesAdapter.java`

```
public class VideoFilesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private List<String> mpath;
    private Context mContext;
    public static ArrayList<String> mSelectedPaths = null;
    private MyLRU lruCache;

    public VideoFilesAdapter(Context context, List<String> path) {
        super(context, R.layout.fileadapter_list, path);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mpath = path;
        // My LRU
        lruCache = MyLRU.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fileadapter_list, null);
            Helper h = new Helper();
            h.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            h.textView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            v.setTag(h);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        Helper myHelper = (Helper) v.getTag();

        File file = new File(mpath.get(position));
        String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        if (file.exists()) {
            myHelper.textView.setText(file.getName());

            Bitmap cacheImage = lruCache.getImage(fullPath);
            if (cacheImage == null) {
                Bitmap bm = scaleCenterCrop(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(fullPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND),100,100);
                lruCache.addImage(fullPath, bm);
                cacheImage = bm;
            }
            myHelper.image.setImageBitmap(cacheImage);

        }

        return v;
    }

    class Helper {
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public static Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
        int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

        // Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
        // To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger
        // of these two.
        float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
        float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
        float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

        // Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
        float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
        float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

        // Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
        // should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
        float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
        float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

        // The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
        // be
        RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);

        // Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
        // scaled bitmap onto it.
        Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
        canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

        return dest;
    }

}
```

As you can see I removed temporarily the `getImageUri` method and the Picasso since it does not make sense already due to that we already have a caching which is LRU-cache.

I hope this will increase your app performance :)

Comment: 07-05 23:14:17.282: E/AndroidRuntime(4681): java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
07-05 23:14:17.282: E/AndroidRuntime(4681):  at com.example.myapp.helper.MyLRU.getImage(MyLRU.java:34)

Comment: I think the problem is your device is out of memory , pls try changing **availableMemory / 8** to **availableMemory / 4** and let me know what will happen.