# How to display local video thumbnails with glide WITHOUT slowing down the listview?

Tags: android, thumbnails, android-glide

I'm trying to display local video thumbnail in this way, it did show the thumbnail in the list. However the list became extremely hard to scroll. 
Is there a better way to solve the problem ?
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos

```
    VideoItem current = (VideoItem) getItem(position);
    mHolder.mTvName.setText(current.getName());
    mHolder.mTvDuration.setText( Utils.convertDuration(current.getDuration()));
    mHolder.mTvSize.setText(formatFileSize(mContext, current.getSize()));


    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(current.getPath())))
            .transform(new GlideRoundTransform(mContext, 12))
            .into(mHolder.mIvIcon);

    return convertView;
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005248/video-thumbnail-arrayadopter-is-slow-on-scroll?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

I found the below answer works too:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(media.getPath()));
Glide.with(getContext()).
load(uri).
thumbnail(0.1f).
into(viewHolderImage.recordedMedia);
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found a solution to this case. 
There is a method with Glide called thumbnail(float sizeMultiplier),it simply compress the size of the original image.Now my listView is more smooth when scrolling.

```
       Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(current.getPath())))
            .transform(new GlideRoundTransform(mContext, 16))
            .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .into(mHolder.mIvIcon);
```

Answer (score -2):

yes, use RecyclerView instead. It doesn't store all picture, just those, fitting on the screen and few hidden for caching

Comment: This is misleading answer, ListView is reusing views if `getView` method properly implemented.